# SpringBoot : getting error while uploading file

Tags: spring-boot

using spring-boot i m trying to post image but i got

`org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException`

> entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="image")
public class ImageEntity {

@Id
@Column(name="imageId")
private String imageId;

@Column(name="imageName")
private String imageName;

@Column(name="type")
private String type;

/*@Column(name="size")
private long size;*/

@Column(name="imagepath")
private String path;

public ImageEntity(String imageName, String type,  String path) {
    super();
    this.imageName = imageName;
    this.type = type;
    //this.size = size;
    this.path = path;
}
```

> Controller Class

```
   @Controller
   public class ImgContr {
    public static final Logger logger =LoggerFactory.getLogger(ImgContr.class);

@Autowired
public ImgService imgService;


@PostMapping("/addImage")
public ImageEntity saveImage(@RequestBody ImageEntity imgent, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws Exception 
{
return imgService.saveImage(imgent );
}
```

> Domain Service

```
@Service
public class ImgService {

@Autowired
public ImageDao imageDao;


public ImageEntity saveImage(ImageEntity imgent) {
    ImageEntity imgEngDom=new ImageEntity();
    imgEngDom.setImageId(imgent.getImageId());
    imgEngDom.setImageName( imgent.getImageName());
    imgEngDom.setPath(imgent.getPath());
    //imgEngDom.setSize(imgent.getSize());
    imgEngDom.setType(imgent.getType());

    return imageDao.saveImage(imgEngDom);

}
```

> ImageDAO.java

```
@Repository
public class ImageDao {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public ImageEntity saveImage(ImageEntity imgEngDom) {

        Session session = null;

        try {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(imgEngDom);

            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();


        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return imgEngDom;

}
```

> Payload Request.

```
  {
    "imageName": "Divya",
    "type" : "jpg",
    "path": " C:/Users/admin/Desktop"
  }
```

//if i try to post image like this below in postman i got error

> Error

{

```
  "timestamp": 1548408353973,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException",
  "message": "Error resolving template \"addImage\", template might not 
  exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template 
  Resolvers",
  "path": "/addImage"
```

}

I am new to `springboot` where i m wrong. Help me.

Comment: is your project is mvc supported or REST-Api ? If you want your controller to serve as an rest API then go with below solution.. It must work. @divya u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem with your Controller configuration.

try this

```
@RestController
public class ImgContr {
```

instead of

```
@Controller
public class ImgContr {
```

For more in-depth details please follow >> [Controller vs RestController](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2017/08/difference-between-restcontroller-and-controller-annotations-spring-mvc-rest.html)

**Note** : Above solution works when you need a json response not a solution for Spring-mvc Projects.

Comment: i have tried that error cleared but imgId is not Auto incremented..if i put@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)  this in Entity class .....and all records are not saved in database

Comment: @divyau if you still facing some other problem or error or exception. Keep posting new question with appropriate code and error stack...

Comment: now i am facing another error that is....imageId is not generated automatically ,even i put @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) this in Entity class ...  and all data is not stored in Database

Comment: no use sir..i got this error Field 'image_id' doesn't have a default value, if i add IDENTITY instead of AUTO..

Comment: i need either AUTO or IDENTITY..in Database i have checked ImageId is not AutoIncremented if i try to alter table it doesnot taken AI..

Comment: please post your complete scenario as an question on stackoverflow.. please mention the flow of execution as well..  i won't be able to identify... what you u trying to ask.. sorry

Comment: @divyau look at your entity field ` imageId` and its a `String` type. please change this field type from `String` to `long`. then `Auto` and `IDENTITY` Generation Strategy will work.. 

Now, i got the error by observing the question